# calling Javascript function without any button to trigger it in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, function

Well, before I proceed to another phase of my coding, just to make sure im not going to bark at the wrong tree, may I ask if it is possible to call a javascript function in php without any button click action to trigger it. i also dont consider onload() or onready() because im going to call the javascript function inside a foreach loop in php.. well the concept goes somehow like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function callMe(){
      alert('im called!');
   }
</script>

<body>
  <?php
    .....
    foreach($somevar as $var){
     // assuming it will loop 5 times
    callMe();  // well this is the part where im going to call the javascript function
   }
  ?>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance.

*********EDITED PART************

here's the actual codes i plan to use:

```
function AddCoordinate( lat, long )                                                                                                                                   
{
  var path = LinePath.getPath(); 
  path.push( new google.maps.LatLng( lat, long ) );
}


<?php    
    foreach($arrayOfPlotPoints as $key => $value){ 
        $longitude = round($value['longitude'],5);
        $latitude = round($value['latitude'],5);
        $snrLevel = $value['snr_level'];
        echo '<script         
            type="text/javascript">AddCoordinate('.$latitude.','.$longitude.')</script>

?>
```

actually that's the right answer..it already worked.. so im gonna provide an answer as well

Comment: What you did is correct
Wrap that with <script type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve? Right now this is not making much sense to do it like this.

Comment: something like an inline javascript?

Comment: im actually going to pass the variables to a javascript function and store it in a javascript array.. that is why right there and then when the values are being exploded in the foreach loop, im going to pass it to the javascript function... i dont want to do it the way like this: store to a variable and pass to javascript

Comment: It *seems* like you are confusing server-side functionality (PHP) with client-side functionality (Javascript). Could you **edit your question** to explain **what you want to achieve** and *then* how you have attempted to achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just output this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">callMe()</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Donatas.. now this is what i have:

```
function AddCoordinate( lat, long )                                                                                                                                   
{
  var path = LinePath.getPath(); 
  path.push( new google.maps.LatLng( lat, long ) );
}


<?php    
    foreach($arrayOfPlotPoints as $key => $value){ 
        $longitude = round($value['longitude'],5);
        $latitude = round($value['latitude'],5);
        $snrLevel = $value['snr_level'];
        echo '<script         
            type="text/javascript">AddCoordinate('.$latitude.','.$longitude.')</script>

?>
```

it works  :)